# How to make reusable proptype validations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reusability, code-reuse, react-proptypes

Assume that I have a parent component called `Logo` which contains two child components respectively `Image` and `Text`. Below code shows how I validate the parent component's props.

```
Logo.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.shape({
      type: PropTypes.oneOf([Image, Text])
    }),
    PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        type: PropTypes.oneOf([Image, Text])
      })
    )
  ])
};
```

This is working fine and does what I really want.
 
But I have so many other components which I do the same children validation nut only the change is `PropTypes.oneOf([Image, Text])` array. So, in that case, I think there should be a common way of using this in javascript/react making this code snippet reusable across the components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could think in a fancier solution, but `propTypes` is really just an object, what if you turn it into a function which receives two parameters `image` and `text` and return an object, so you could just import it in your components:

```
export const myPropTypesCreator = (image, text) =>({/*return the object*/})
```

And inside your components:

```
import { myPropTypesCreator } from './mypath'
Logo.propTypes = myPropTypesCreator(image,text)
```